Use of plurals in mixed context
In a language app, I encountered a translation of "2 apples" as
Два яблоко
I would have thought it to be
Два яблоки (or Две яблоки)
Is that just my English bias showing?
Thanks.

Both are wrong. The correct option is "два яблока"

I could have sworn we had at least three answers to that, but all I could find was about adjectives, not nouns

The rule is as follows:

If the numeral ends in один/одна/одно, the noun complement is in the singular nominative: одно яблоко, двадцать одно яблоко
If the numeral ends in два/две, три, четыре, the noun complement is in the singular genitive: два яблока, тридцать три яблока
Otherwise, the noun complement is in the plural genitive: восемь яблок, пятнадцать яблок, сорок яблок.

Here's the algorithm:

If the last two digits of the number are between 11 to 19, inclusive, then pl. gen., else
If the last digit of the number is 1, then sg. nom., else
If the last digit of the number is from 2 to 4, inclusive, then sg. gen., else
Pl. gen.


The gender is neuter ( “-o” ending), the case is genitive, so in this case the ending will be “-a”, that is два яблока. It’s important to know the gender of the noun and after that to change it according to the case.
